# Solve Lagrange Partial Differential Equation: $x^3p + y(3 x^2 + y)q = z(2 x^2 + y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am unable to solve this Lagrange PDE: 
$$
x^3 p + y(3 x^2 + y) q = z(2 x^2 + y),
$$
where $p = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, $q = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

I have found the $c_1 = \dfrac{xz}{y}$.

Unable to find the multipliers to find out $c_2$ to get the complete integral $f(c_1,c_2) = 0$.

Comment: You probably made a mistake. $c=\frac{xy}{z}$ is not correct. You should find $c=\frac{xz}{y}$ or something equivalent.

Comment: Yeah...It was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^3z_x+y(3x^2+y)z_y=z(2x^2+y)$$
The characteristic relationships are :
$$\frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac{dy}{y(3x^2+y)}=\frac{dz}{z(2x^2+y)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac{dy}{y(3x^2+y)}$
Solving this first order linear ODE gives :
$$x+\frac{x^3}{y}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation is more difficult to derive. We need a combination of the above differential equations :
$$\frac{ydx}{yx^3}=\frac{-xdy}{-xy(3x^2+y)}=\frac{ydx-xdy}{yx^3-xy(3x^2+y)}=
\frac{ydx-xdy}{-xy(2x^2+y)}$$
$$\frac{ydx-xdy}{-xy(2x^2+y)}=\frac{dz}{z(2x^2+y)}$$
$$\frac{ydx-xdy}{-xy}=\frac{dz}{z}$$
$$\ln|z|+\ln|x|-\ln|y|=\text{constant}$$
$$z\frac{x}{y}=c_2$$
The general solution expressed on implicit form is :
$$\Phi\left(x+\frac{x^3}{y}\:,\:z\frac{x}{y}\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

This implicit equation can be solved for $z$ , which gives the solution:
$$z(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}F\left(x+\frac{x^3}{y}\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

Comment: How did you solve the first characteristic equation?

Comment: @ Dom Jo. $y'=\frac{y^2}{x^3}+3\frac{y}{x}$ is a Riccati ODE. Proceed with the usual change of function : Thus $y=-x^3\frac{u'}{u}$ leading to $u''=0$ and then $u=c_0(x-c_1)$ and $y=\frac{x^3}{c_1-x}$.